# Найти количество различных элементов в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, visual-studio

Дан одномерный массив размером `N`. Надо найти количество различных элементов.

Помогите написать код, уже голова не соображает.

Comment: Раз одномерный массив, то только N = 1... :)

Comment: @Harry размер != размерность.

Comment: @älёxölüt Размерность на размер - это уже я исправил :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да масса способов.

```
sort(begin(a),end(a));
distance(begin(a),unique(begin(a),end(a)));
```

Или, например, запихивать все в `set/unordered_set`, а потом посмотреть, сколько там элементов...